# How to print consonant letter and stop the loop if the user input a vowel?

Tags: java, loops

The problem of my code is that it doesn't stop the loop even though you input a vowel, and when I try to  transfer the code to the online compiler it says

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
    at Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

However, in the app called java N-IDE it works fine.

Here is the code:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

char letter;

do{

letter = in.next().charAt(0); //the line 12 is this.
System.out.println(letter);

}while(letter != 'A' || letter != 'e' || letter != 'i' || letter != 'o' || letter != 'u');
```

PS: It's not exactly online compiler, the website is called code chum where you can learn Java and it has compiler in it. That's where my lesson is.

Comment: Please show a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem *"doesn't stop the loop even though you input a vowel"* you said, it's because you need to change your condition from *OR* to *AND*. For example, when you enter something like `apple` the `letter != 'a'` is false, but the second condition which is `letter != 'e'` is true, then the loop will continue. so you need to change it to `&&` (*AND*).

Also the `letter != 'A'` is different from `letter != 'a'` so I changed the input to lowercase:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

char letter;

int counter = 0;

do {
    counter++;
    letter = in.next().charAt(0); // the line 12 is this.
    System.out.println(letter);
    letter = Character.toLowerCase(letter);
} while ((letter != 'a' && letter != 'e' && letter != 'i' && letter != 'o' && letter != 'u') && counter < 5);
```

Comment: @Johny: yes, you can use `Character.toUpperCase(letter)` and change it to uppercase and compare.

Comment: how do i make it to count to 5 letters only? the loop doesn't stops if i enter 5 letter without the vowel. i try this ```letter != '5'``` still doesn't stop unless i input a vowel. @Mustafa Poya

Comment: @Johny you want to enter `5` or a string with length of 5 character?

Comment: I want it to make enter a length of 5 characters only. the user only need to input 5 letters and the loop stop unless the user enter a vowel earlier then the loop stop. @Mustafa Poya

Comment: do you want to your `do-while` stop after 5 iteration?

Comment: yes, how would I do that ? @Mustafa Poya

Comment: @Johny, I Updated the code and now it check whether its a vowel or reached to 5 then will end the loop.

Comment: thank you, you have been very helpful @Mustafa Poya

Answer (score 1):

Your loop condition says to loop while (letter != 'A' or letter != 'e' etc)

So if the user inputs 'A', the first condition is false, but the second condition is true, so the loop continues. In other words, nothing the user can input will stop the loop.

Try changing the or condition to be && (and) instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    char letter;
    letter = in.next().charAt(0);

    while(letter != 'A' && letter != 'E' && letter != 'I' && letter != 'O' && letter != 'U'&&letter != 'a' && letter != 'e' && letter != 'i' && letter != 'o' && letter != 'u' ){

    
    System.out.println(letter);
    letter = in.next().charAt(0); //the line 12 is this.

    }**This code may help you**
```